# python bottle framework - How to pass dictionary to nested template?

Tags: python, templates, bottle

I am using python's bottle framework to develop a simple web page. I am having trouble understanding how to pass a dictionary to a subtemplate. Example code:

mydictionary:

```
{
message: "Hello World",
...other template vars ... 
}
```

Router.py

```
@route('/index.html')
@view('index.tpl')
def index():
    return mydictionary
```

views/index.tpl

```
<body>
%include subpage1 ......  <-- need to pass mydictionary here
...other stuff ...
</body>
```

views/subpage1.tpl

```
<div>This is a test: {{message}}</div>
```

The [documentation page](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html) states:

> *The %include Statement: You can include other templates using the %include sub_template [kwargs] statement. The sub_template parameter
>   specifies the name or path of the template to be included. The rest of
>   the line is interpreted as a comma-separated list of key=statement
>   pairs similar to keyword arguments in function calls. They are passed
>   to the sub-template analogous to a SimpleTemplate.render() call. The
>   **kwargs syntax for passing a dict is allowed too*:

However, no example is given on how to pass dictionary with this **kwargs to subtemplates.  Anyone ever done this? If I just say %include subpage1 mydictionary, bottle complains mydictionary is undefined (even though mydictionary is a global dict [defined in Router.py]).

regards
GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by doing the following in the template file:

views/index.tpl

```
<body>
%from mydictfile import * <-- importing mydict here
%include subpage1 mydict  
...other stuff ...
</body>
```

mydictfile:

```
mydict = {
message: "Hello World",
...other template vars ... 
}
```

This seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need keyword arguments. try:

```
%include subpage1 mydict=mydict ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that dictionary will not be defined by me. It will be given by a client (essentially a language translation of various words). So I just want to read that file into mydict and pass it to the subpage.

Comment: The expresion a=b in the include means that the variable b will be called a in the subpage. (Call by reference).

Comment: You can use the same name in the subpage to make things clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the help .. tried that ... but it gave NameError: 'mydict' name not defined.  However, I found another method to do this. So I'll answer my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on @G.A.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624600), I accessed a variable defined in my main program in my template with:

```
% from __main__ import app
blah blah {{app.config.my_config}} blah
```

Edit: Under Python 2.6 I had to use (to import from mybottleapp.py):

```
% from mybottleapp import app
```

I am not enough of a Python expert to understand why this is so.