# def function in python in a tpl file?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bottle

Can you define a function inside of a template file? If not, can you import a custom python lib in the .tpl file to call a function?

This is the function I am trying to call:

```
%def rec_print(obj):
    %if "output" not in rec_print.__dict__: rec_print.output = ""
    %end
    %if isinstance(obj, unicode):
        %rec_print.output += "<li>"+str(obj)+ "</li>"
    %elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        %for k, v in obj.items():
            %rec_print.output += "<li>" +str(k) +"</li><ul>"
            %rec_print(v)
            %rec_print.output += "</ul>\n"
    %elif isinstance(obj, list):
        %for items in obj:
            %rec_print(items)
    %else:
        %print "uknown type for", obj, type(obj)
    %end
    %return rec_print.output
%end
```

I use this function to generate content that I get from my mongodb in a bottle powered webapp.

Comment: I think you can if you use mako.

Comment: Is that a different framework? I will probably eventually change to django, but I want to take bottle as far as I can.

Comment: Nope, its a templating language, and I think you can install it as a `bottle` framework.

Comment: Ugh... starting over... okay, I'll take a look. Can you do something with /__main__  (idea from <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614116/python-bottle-framework-how-to-pass-dictionary-to-nested-template">here</a>.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Templates: Fast and pythonic built-in template engine and support for mako, jinja2 and cheetah templates.

From bottle's website.

You can use Mako, which is a templating language for Python. You can use it with bottle. Here is a section on [Defs and Blocks](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html).

Comment: So, to switch from bottle's built in templating, I would have to specify a filename and a dictionary variable when passing it in?

Comment: @Jeff Thats a separate question, and I encourage you to ask it separately as a SO question. In the mean time, you can accept this one.